# Поэлементное слияние 3+ списков

Tags: python, list, списки

Имеется множество списков и их конечное количество неизвестно. Как их объединить в список списков?

Например:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
b = [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

f= list(map(list, zip(a, b)))
print(f)
```

Получаю:

```
[[1, 6], [2, 7], [3, 8], [4, 9], [5, 10]]
```

К сожалению дальше начинается полная каша:

```
c = [11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
f= list(map(list, zip(f, c)))
print(f)
```

Получается:

```
[[[1, 6], 11], [[2, 7], 12], [[3, 8], 13], [[4, 9], 14], [[5, 10], 15]]
```

А нужно:

```
[[1, 6, 11], [2, 7, 12], [3, 8, 13], [4, 9, 14], [5, 10, 15]]
```

Что делаю не так?

Comment: в вопросе конечно же списки а не словари. остатки мозга потеряны

Comment: Передайте в zip сразу три списка (все списки, которые нужно объединить)

Comment: можно, но конечное количество списков неизвестно => непонятно сколько их передавать в zip. Это очень упрощенный пример довольно нетривиальной задачи для меня. Самый простой вариант, это в цикле пройтись по полученным данным и склеить их в список списков

Comment: Положить все списки в список и передать их в zip через звёздочку?

Comment: отличный совет, спасибо огромное. действительно соберу список списков в цикле и передам в зип всю кашицу

Answer (score 2):

Объединить сразу много списков: собираете списки в общий список, дальше пропускаете этот общий список через `zip`:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
b = [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
c = [11, 12, 13, 14, 15]

d = [a, b, c]
f = list(map(list, zip(*d)))
```

Добавлять списки по одному:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
b = [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

f= list(map(list, zip(a, b)))

c = [11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
f = [x + [y] for x, y in zip(f, c)]
# Через map не так красиво: f = list(map(lambda t: t[0] + [t[1]], zip(f, c)))
print(f)
# [[1, 6, 11], [2, 7, 12], [3, 8, 13], [4, 9, 14], [5, 10, 15]]
```

Или просто циклом:

```
c = [11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
for x, y in zip(f, c):
    x.append(y)
print(f)
```